# What happens if an unhadelled exception occurs at wcf service side during a method call?

Tags: wcf, channelfactory

I mean if a wcf client makes a call to wcf method, and then if wcf generates an exception which is uncaught at wcf side,
then it is my understanding that this error/exception at wcf side breaks the channel established between client/wcf by wcf proxy object(only if uncaught at wcf side)?

Is that true?

If true,then if i want to use same proxy object again (which was used to call wcf method when exception occurred) to make another call to wcf, may be in catch block at client end (may be for retrial of last call), then is there any way i can use that

or need to create/use new new proxy object?